# create a loop of posts from database

Tags: php, mysql

It's my first code using phpmyadmin database .... and it doesen't work can someone help me :)

```
<?php
    $bdd = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=mydatabase, root, ');// serveur test
    $requete = $bdd->query('SELECT * FROM posts');
    while($data = $requete->fetch()){
    echo'<article class="format-standard">
             <div class="feature-image">
                 <a href="page.php?id='.$data['id'].'" data-rel="prettyPhoto"><img src="'.$data['img'].'" alt="Alt text" /></a>
             </div>
             <h1>
                 <a href="page.php?id='.$data['id'].'" class="post-heading">'.$data['title'].'</a>
             </h1>
             <div class="meta">
                 <span class="entry-date">'.$data['date'].'</span>
                 in
                 <span class="categories">
                     <a href="#">Category 1</a>,
                     <a href="#">Category 2</a>
                 </span>
             </div>
             <div class="excerpt">'.$data['description'].'</div>
             <a href="page.php?id='.$data['id'].'" class="read-more">read more</a>
         </article>';
    };
    $requete->closeCursor();                
?>
```

i want create some posts on my page and i have trouble with category :( any help please !

Comment: can you please show us the structure of your table?

Comment: `phpmyadmin database` that's very interesting...

Comment: What's the error you are getting?

Comment: @BlackGhost: PHPMyAdmin is NOT a database, also tell us your error message.

Comment: @amenadiel i don't see anything my page is empty

Comment: @Jevison7x i didn't mean it's a database i mean it's the first time i work on it

Comment: @Cristian the structure ==> https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/-C3aVdRjmt5A/U5X45I3t4FI/AAAAAAAAAxw/SuPGrGF_cDM/w1116-h224-no/Ashampoo_Snap_2014.06.09_19h09m30s_001_.png

Comment: you don't have any category field in your table... i can't understand where is the problem related to categories.

Comment: no i want to creat category later I tried but it not work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are plenty of things that might be going wrong, but the first one seems to be your connection string. You're passing a single parameter, but the username should be a second parameter.

instead of

```
$bdd = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=mydatabase, root, ');// serveur test
```

try

```
$bdd = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=mydatabase','root');
```

let's clear that up before continuing.

**Edit**: if there's a password, it would be the third parameter. It's optional BTW.

Comment: I have password but I hid it !

Comment: @BlackGhost , thats not the problem what amenadiel is talking about. you are giving 1 string.. but the pdo class expact 3 parameters... first the string, than another one (username) and the third is password...

Comment: yes I just spoke with the first (first comment) delted he told me to create a password